# how should I rotate this tree to change it into balanced AVL tree?

Tags: binary-search-tree, avl-tree

```
           How could I change this linear tree to balanced tree in single traversal?
```

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
       \
        5 
         \ 
          6
```

How many rotations should I do to change this into AVL tree?.

Comment: Are the input nodes already equiped with balance-factor information, as is needed for AVL nodes? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new empty AVL tree and insert each of the elements of your tree into this. Follow the example on wikipedia for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree?wprov=sfti1

Answer (score 0):

At least 3 rotations are needed.

Because the root has a bad balance 5, rotate the root 2 times.

Go up to the second floor.

4 has a bad balance 2, so rotate it 1 time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).